# How to have a user pick a player position and have mySQL show every player in my database with that position?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm able to make a MySQL Database using PHP, fill it up with my data, and have it pop up on my webpage. However, I want the user to be able to click from a Options DropDown a position in Football, say QuarterBack, and then the webpage will display only the players on the team that are quarterbacks.

I'm pretty sure all I need is something to do with my line of `SELECT * FROM`

**EDIT** -- ALSO, my code on the webpage says Unidentified Index - Position, even though i define it

Relevant Code information is here:

```
<form action="FinalProject.php" method="get">
    <select name="position" id="position" value="position">
        <option value="">Select a position:</option>
        <option value="1">Quarterback</option>
        <option value="2">Wide Receiver</option>
        <option value="3">Linebacker</option>
        <option value="4">Tight End</option>
    </select>
</form>

<?php
//                     --- CREATE THE DATABASE
$db_conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$db_conn)
    die("Unable to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_query($db_conn, "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS sportDatabase;");

// --- CREATE THE TABLE
mysqli_select_db($db_conn, "sportDatabase");
$cmd = "CREATE TABLE bearsRoster (
          number int(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
          playerName varchar(20),
          position char(2),
          height varchar(5),
          weight int(3),
          age int(2),
          experience int(2),
          collegeName varchar(50)
          );";

mysqli_query($db_conn, $cmd);
$cmd = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'bearsRoster.csv' INTO TABLE bearsRoster FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';";
mysqli_query($db_conn, $cmd);
$selectedOption = $_GET["position"];
$cmd = "SELECT * FROM bearsRoster ";
//                    ORDER BY position WHERE".$selectedOption.";";
$records = mysqli_query($db_conn, $cmd);

echo("<table border = 'black' align:'center'> 
        <tr> 
        <th>Number</th> 
        <th>Player Name</th> 
        <th>Position</th> 
        <th>Height</th> 
        <th>Weight</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Experience</th>
        <th>College Name</th>
        </tr>" . PHP_EOL);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {
    echo("<tr> 
            <td id = 'yellow'>" . $row['number'] . "</td> 
            <td id = 'red'>" . $row['playerName'] . "</td> 
            <td id = 'red'>" . $row['position'] . "</td> 
            <td id = 'blue'>" . $row['height'] . "</td>
            <td id = 'blue'>" . $row['weight'] . "</td>
            <td id = 'pink'>" . $row['age'] . "</td>
            <td id = 'pink'>" . $row['experience'] . "</td>
            <td id = 'pink'>" . $row['collegeName'] . "</td>
          </tr>" . PHP_EOL);
}
echo("</table>");
mysqli_close($db_conn);
?>
```

Comment: How do you actually post the form? Is there a button that is not included? Or some Javascript AJAX?

If this is the full script it ain't gonne work now because just changing the form does not actually do anything yet if there is no Javascript catching the event or a button that is pressed so the form is processed.

Comment: @Cpt.Kangar00  I had this button in my code before, but even with the button, form, and an IF button clicked statement in my PHP code, the webpage would still load with the entirity of MySQL database already showing. `<button id="displayRoster" value="displayRoster" type="submit" name="button">List Roster</button>

                 if (isset($_GET["button"])){
                    if( $_GET["button"] == "displayRoster"){`

Comment: @richardjames you can use ajax to fetch the data from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code a bit and I this should work.

```
<form action="FinalProject.php" method="POST">
    <select name="position" id="position" value="position">
        <option value="">Select a position:</option>
        <option value="QB">Quarterback</option>
        <option value="WR">Wide Receiver</option>
        <option value="LB">Linebacker</option>
        <option value="TE">Tight End</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click me!" />
</form>

<?php
$db_conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$db_conn)
    die("Unable to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_query($db_conn, "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS sportDatabase;");
mysqli_select_db($db_conn, "sportDatabase");

$cmd = "CREATE TABLE bearsRoster (number int(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, playerName varchar(20), position char(2), height varchar(5), weight int(3), age int(2), experience int(2), collegeName varchar(50));";
mysqli_query($db_conn, $cmd);

$cmd = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'bearsRoster.csv' INTO TABLE bearsRoster FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';"; 
mysqli_query($db_conn, $cmd);

$cmd = "SELECT * FROM bearsRoster";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if($_POST['position'] == 'QB' || $_POST['position'] == 'WR' || $_POST['position'] == 'LB' || $_POST['position'] == 'TE')
        $selectedOption = $_POST['position'];
    else
        $selectedOption = null;

    if($selectedOption !== null)
        $cmd = "SELECT * FROM bearsRoster WHERE position = ".$selectedOption.";";
}

$records = mysqli_query($db_conn, $cmd);

echo("<table border = 'black' align:'center'><tr><th>Number</th><th>Player Name</th><th>Position</th><th>Height</th><th>Weight</th><th>Age</th><th>Experience</th><th>College Name</th></tr>" . PHP_EOL);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)){
    echo("<tr><td id = 'yellow'>" . $row['number'] . "</td><td id = 'red'>" . $row['playerName'] . "</td><td id = 'red'>" . $row['position'] . "</td><td id = 'blue'>" . $row['height'] . "</td><td id = 'blue'>". $row['weight'] . "</td><td id = 'pink'>". $row['age'] . "</td><td id = 'pink'>". $row['experience'] . "</td><td id = 'pink'>". $row['collegeName'] . "</td></tr>". PHP_EOL);
}

echo("</table>");
mysqli_close($db_conn);
```

Comment: This seems like it will work, i put it into my file, but Now I just realized I have for instance `<option value="1">Quarterback</option>` and yet no way of actually telling my database that value 1 = QB in the Position Column. any quick tip with that? I thought the `(is_numeric($_POST))` would fix that

Comment: Ah you use two letter codes. I thought they were numeric as in your form. What are the codes?

Comment: Well I originally had them as Value="1", but I just changed it to Value="QB" and so on for each position because that just makes more sense than to have it as a numeric value. Also, I don't know how to have the value="1" actually equal every QB position on the time, I'm uploading a small sample of what the database looks like now as well

Comment: I changed the code a bit so it uses two letter codes.

Comment: Heres what the database looks like if this helps http://imgur.com/a/LiFjw

Comment: Not sure where the syntax error is, it says in line 153 `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' `, but it seems all in place.. however the {} of that section is showing red on my editor

Comment: @richardjames can you copy paste the code in line 153?

Comment: ` $selectedOption = ($_POST['position'] == 'QB' || $_POST['position'] == 'WR' || $_POST['position'] == 'LB' || $_POST['position'] == 'TE') ? $_POST['position'] : null);`

Comment: I hate to be a pain, so before when it was just my code, My entire database would automatically just pop up on the page (Which I did not want). Now with your code, it has the options for positions, and I click, page refreshes, but no table shows up (Just the headers for each column like Name|Position|Weight|Height and so on. So I think the last part of the code where it's `While($row_ = mysqli_fetch_array($records)){` isn't actually printing out the results

Comment: Did you copy paste the code? As there is no underscore behind the $row in my code. That underscore will make the table be empty.

Comment: yea I copied and pasted the entirety of it without changing (that underscore was a typo of mine in the comments)

Comment: This is my issue, when I click Wide Reciever for instance, the error comes back as "Error: Unknown column 'WR' in 'where clause'"

Comment: Try this:
$cmd = "SELECT * FROM bearsRoster WHERE position = '".$selectedOption."';";

I've added two single quotes around the selectedOption

Answer (score 0):

Use `IF NOT EXISTS` in your table creation as this will delete and create your table each time you run the script. You can use [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) to fetch data from the server without reloading the page or redirecting.

> AJAX is a developer's dream, because you can:
>
> - Update a web page without reloading the page
> - Request data from a server - after the page has loaded
> - Receive data from a server - after the page has loaded
> - Send data to a server - in the background

In your `select` add [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) attribute that will call a Javascript function which will fetch the data from the database and display it on the page without reloading.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<select name="position" id="position" onchange="getPosition(this)" value="position">
    <option value="">Select a position:</option>
    <option value="QB">Quarterback</option>
    <option value="WR">Wide Receiver</option>
    <option value="LB">Linebacker</option>
    <option value="TE">Tight End</option>
</select>

<div id="results"></div>
<script>
    function getPosition(position) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "FinalProject.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send('position=' + position.value);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**FinalProject.php**

```
<?php
//                     --- CREATE THE DATABASE
$db_conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$db_conn)
    die("Unable to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_query($db_conn, "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS sportDatabase;");

// --- CREATE THE TABLE
mysqli_select_db($db_conn, "sportDatabase");
$cmd = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bearsRoster (
          number int(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
          playerName varchar(20),
          position char(2),
          height varchar(5),
          weight int(3),
          age int(2),
          experience int(2),
          collegeName varchar(50)
          );";

mysqli_query($db_conn, $cmd);
$cmd = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'bearsRoster.csv' INTO TABLE bearsRoster FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';";
mysqli_query($db_conn, $cmd);
$selectedOption = $_POST["position"];
$cmd = "SELECT * FROM `bearsRoster` WHERE position = '$selectedOption' ORDER BY position";
$records = mysqli_query($db_conn, $cmd);

if ($records && mysqli_num_rows($records)) : ?>
    <table border='black' align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Player Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Height</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Experience</th>
            <th>College Name</th>
        </tr>

        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))  : ?>
            <tr>
                <td id='yellow'><?php echo $row['number']; ?></td>
                <td id='red'><?php echo $row['playerName']; ?></td>
                <td id='red'><?php echo $row['position']; ?></td>
                <td id='blue'><?php echo $row['height']; ?></td>
                <td id='blue'><?php echo $row['weight']; ?></td>
                <td id='pink'><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
                <td id='pink'><?php echo $row['experience']; ?></td>
                <td id='pink'><?php echo $row['collegeName']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
<?php else: ?>
<h1>No Data found</h1>
<?php endif;
mysqli_close($db_conn);
?>
```

Comment: Does this go with Cpt.Kangar00's code? because his code works very well for me for what i need where it comes to a dropdown menu, click the position, and only show players with that position. My big issue now is that the database is completely on my page when i first load up the page, even before i click any buttons...its just always there

Comment: it gives the error  Undefined index: position and also NO DATA FOUND is stated right under it

Comment: yup, both. and not only that, but when i try to select a position, it really messes up with my page by having everything move around as well

Comment: thats basically exactly what I want. I'm not sure why that won't work with mine..

Comment: I uploaded my entire php file into that. The only thing missing is a css file which just plays with buttons and what not

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What i uploaded to codeshare.io is the entirety of my FinalProject.php file. Nothing else is needed to run it (other than running with XAMPP on, not sure if you are using a localhost for that because i am) also, it is missing my excel sheet that has the info for the roster

Comment: FinalProject.php is the main page?

Comment: yeah, you run it through a local host server and it starts with the html and what not, the php in that code i pasted into the codeshare only deals with my MySQL Database stuff

Comment: The players needs to be displayed in `PHPDiv`?

Comment: yeah so that when i switch to the tab that the page with that Div is on, it will only show up on that tab, not on every page of my website

Comment: But the youtube video is displayed over the div, nvm check this https://hypotactic-snow.000webhostapp.com/